# how to programmatically handle navigation from backing bean in jsf2

Tags: jsf-2

I want to be able to do semething in the likes of:

```
 @ManagedBean
 class MyBackingBean {
     public void processRequest() {
         String viewName;
         if (condition1) 
             viewName = "page1";
         else if (condition2) 
             viewName = "pagexx";     

         invokeAndRenderXHTML(viewName);
     }
 }
```

thanks

Comment: why not just return the viewname as string and invoke the bean method from the action attribute on a button

Comment: in our application, by the time processRequest() is called, no human interaction is possible

Comment: from the sounds of it, you need the client to make a new request. either you can have the client polling once in a while, or use websockets to make it event driven.

Comment: So... You want to send a HTTP response without a HTTP request? If that were really possible, the world wide web would have looked very different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just in case anyone stumbles upon this old question: 
you can programatically invoke navigation handler like this

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), null, "YOUR_NAVIGATION_CASE_DEFINED_IN_FACES_CONFIG");
```

Answer (score 1):

JSF provides programmatic navigation by default. You do **NOT** need a third party library to effect navigation. To use JSF navigation, your method should simply return the name of the view you're trying to access and it'll navigate to that page. You could also include an optional `redirect` parameter to the return value to instruct the JSF context to redirect the response in full to the destination view. For your needs, just change `processRequest` to

```
   public String processRequest() {
     // String viewName unnecessary
     if (condition1) {
        return "page1";
              }
     else if (condition2) {
        return = "pagexx";  
           }
        return null;   
    // invokeAndRenderXHTML(viewName) becomes unnecessary
    }
```

If you choose to have the `redirect` option like I indicated above just change the return String to

```
    return "page1?faces-redirect=true"
```

the `faces-redirect=true` is the parameter that does the redirect magic

Answer (score -1):

as you need a request to trigger a response i think there are two ways to go. either polling or push.

www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf

www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/index.jsf

Check out primefaces showcase of both to get an understanding on which suits your need best. Even if you dont use the library you can look at the sources to get a better understanding of how to do this in jsf2

Comment: This is grossly misleading. The `poll` and `push` components are bad options for navigation, moreso when they're completely unnecessary for OP's use case.

Comment: @kolo from the comments you can see that the navigation should not only be programatic, but also happpen without user interaction.

Comment: @kolossus failed with the name-tagging in the above comment, anyways i think your answer is part of what the OP is asking for.